# SQL Server find the missing number

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table like below

```
id  name  year
--------------
1    A     2000
2    B     2000
2    B     2000
2    B     2000
5    C     2000
1    D     2001
3    E     2001
```

as well as you see in the year 2000 we missed id '3' and id '4' and in the year 2001 we missed id '2'. I want to generate my second table which includes missed items.

2nd table :

```
From-id   to-id    name    year
--------------------------------
3          4        null   2000
2          null     null   2001
```

Which method in a SQL query can solve my problem?

Comment: search for "using a numbers or tally table"

Comment: Do you have another table containing the `id`s?

Comment: i didnt get you Mr Alireza !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gaps and Islands in Sequences is the name of this problem. you read this [article](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/the-sql-of-gaps-and-islands-in-sequences/)

Answer (score 1):

Here's something to get you started:

```
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM 
    (VALUES
    (1),(2),(3),(4),(5)
    ) Tally(number)
), cte2 as
(
    SELECT DISTINCT [year]
    FROM
    (VALUES
    (2000),(2000),(2001)
    )tbl([year])
), cte3 as
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM cte
    CROSS JOIN cte2
)
SELECT * 
FROM cte3
LEFT OUTER JOIN YourTable ON cte3.number = YourTable.id AND cte3.[year] = YourTable[year)
```

A few notes: please avoid using reserved keywords as column names (such as year).
Furthermore, since I didn't know how you'd handle multiple missing ranges I did not format the output to reflect a range. For example: What would be your expected output if only one row with id=3 would be in your table?

Comment: Thank you but whatever i wrote in the question was a simple table , my real table is consist of over 100k records . its not possible to use values for it .

Comment: Remember, we only know what you tell us. Without table definition, sample data, expected result based on those sample it's impossible to get a solution that you'll only need to copy and paste. The values approach is caused by the lack of any more detailed information. You'll either need to provide more information or replace the values with select statements.

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably use ROW_NUMBER for this

This query gives you what the correct ID should be (if I interpreted your question right):

```
SELECT 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY yr ORDER BY name, yr) as "Correct ID", *
FROM misorder
```

It assigns a row number (so a number starting from 1 increasing by 1 every time the year is the same).

And to let you know which ones are missing I think this should be a working solution:

```
WITH missing AS
(
    SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY yr ORDER BY name, yr) as "Correct ID", *
    FROM misorder
)
SELECT * FROM missing
WHERE "Correct ID" != "id"
```

It takes the first query as a base to select only those records where the assumed correct ID is not equal to the currently assigned ID. You can turn this into a query to include the ranges you mentioned, but not sure if that is really necessary.

Hope this helps.